# How to Backup and Restore ORACLE Database 11g Like SQL2005 Database

Tags: oracle11g

I created database in oracle 11g this database name are "test".
and then i created new user in test database. i connect to created new user and password and then create table, procedure and triggers in SQL Developer.
i will backup this test database and restore in another pc. please help me step by step how to backup and restore.

Comment: Actually a simple google search would have given the answer you required

Comment: Actually a simple Google search gives this page as a result, Google does not store the answers to questions, websites like StackOverflow do!

Comment: Actually a simple google search did only return pretty complicated results, videos and how to do it from Windows, Gnome or KDE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To transfer your user(schema) with all related objects(table, triggers and so on) to another computer with Oracle 11g installed on, you can do the following:

On a first computer (where you have your user created) use [exp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm#1013411) command line utility to unload user's(schema's) data to an OS file(dump file).

```
exp userid=yourusername/youruserpassword@Connect_Identifier File=OSPath
Example
Exp userid=scott/tiger@ORCL file=c:\scott.dmp
```

transfer created *.dmp file  to another computer with Oracle 11 installed on and use [imp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1656) command line utility to load *.dmp file into a NEW (it means you have to create a user id it doesn't exist already ) created schema(users)

```
 imp userid/password@Connect_identifier fromuser=user_name_you_have_data_unloaded_from touser=new_user_name file=Path_to_*.dmp file
```

As you are using Oracle 11g you can use [Data pump Export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#i1007466) and [Data Pump Import](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#i1007653) utilities to do the same thing. [Exp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm#1013411) and [Imp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch02.htm#1656) are there for backward compatibility but the will work as expected.